# Angular: injecting state into controllers (or binding "models" to controllers)

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Suppose I have a general purpose controller, TableController, that can be used in multiple places in the app to display a table of Key x Value pairs via a custom directive, ui-table, that generates an HTML table.

```
angular.module('ui.table', [])
  .controller('TableController', ['$scope', 'data', 
     function($scope, data) { $scope.data = data; }])
  .directive('uiTable', function() {
    return { templateUrl: 'table.html' }
});
```

I could use the controller in the following template:

```
<div ng:controller="TableController">
  <div ui-table></div>
</div>
```

And create a factory to pass data to this controller.

```
.factory('data', function() {
  return [{'App':'Demo', 'Version':'0.0.1'}];
})
```

But, I have multiple controllers (sometimes in the same views), so I need to "bind" a particular factory to a particular controller (e.g., UserProfile, AppData, etc.)

I have started to look at angular-ui-router's $stateProvider, but it seems too complicated for what must be a typical use case? What I'd really like to be able to do is use the template to annotate which factory (what I think of as a model) should be used for that particular controller. E.g., something like:

```
<div ng:controller="TableController" ng:model="AppData"></div>
```

What is the right approach?

EDIT:

I've figured out $stateProvider and "resolve" allows me to map provider services onto injected values for the state's main controller -- but the controller I want to influence is a child of this controller.

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/home/view.html',
        controller: 'MainViewController',
        resolve: {
          'data': 'AppData'
        }
      });
```

So, I still can't figure out how to influence the controllers inside the state's view.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble by using table/grid modules that are already available that are set up either as declarative in the view or scope configurable. There are numerous choices around. Just a matter of feature checking against your needs. Or use them for inspiration to build your own

Comment: I think what you need is to implement *directive* instead of controller. As you've already know, you can pass a paticular scope data to a particular directive as you like.

Comment: @charlietfl, I'm trying to understand how Angular works, so this is just an example.

Comment: @yazaki, thanks, but I do have a directive that uses the scope. The problem is how do the appropriate values get into the scope? They have to be set by the controller -- which is the problem I'm bringing up: how can I bind these values to the right controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is simply passing your data into the directive through attributes. Then use an isolated scope in directive so you can have multiple instances active at the same time

```
<div ng-controller="ViewController">
    <div ui-table dataSource="tableData"></div>
</div>
```

Then your directive would be written in a generic way to be re-usable regardless of the data passed in.

```
.factory('SomeService', function(){
      var data ={
           headings: ['ID','Age','Name'],
           rows:[
             {id:1, 33,'Bill'}......
           ]
      };
      return {
         get:function(){ return data;}
      };
 }) 

.controller('ViewController', function($scope, SomeService){
    $scope.tableData = SomeService.get();
})

.directive.directive('uiTable', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            dataSource: '=' // isolated scope, 2 way binding 
        }
        templateUrl: 'table.html',
        controller: 'TableController', // this controller can be injected in children directives using `require`

    }
});
```

In essence this is just reversing your layout of controller/directive. Instead of `TableController` wrapping the directive, it is used internally within directive. The only reason it is a `controller` in the directive is to allow it to be `require`'d by child directives such as perhaps row directive or headings directive and even cell directive. Otherwise if not needing to expose it for injection you can use `link` and put all sorts of table specific operations in there

As mentioned in my comments there are various approaches to creating a table directive. One is with heavy configuration objects, the other is with a lots of declarative view html that use many child directives. I would suggest analyzing the source of several different grid/table modules to see what best suits your coding style

Comment: I agree. This is what I imagined.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl this is really helpful (esp. the directive scope part).

Still, the problem I had was not wanting to hard code the service in the parent controller. In other words I want to inject into directive any named service. I'm going to post what I mean in another answer below; would appreciate your comments.

Comment: But you would always need to do that to pass the data to directive. If directive is constructed properly it wouldn't matter which service in your you get data from, or even just making `$http` calls in each view controller where directive is used

Comment: Thanks again for the response -- could you please comment on my updated answer below? (Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks in part to @charlietfl (above) I have an answer:

```
<ui-graph model="SomeGraphModel"></ui-graph>
```

Then:

```
angular.module('ui.graph', [])

  .directive('uiGraph', [function() {
    return {
      controller: 'GraphController',
      scope: {
        model: '@model' // Bind the element's attribute to the scope.
      }
    }
  }]);

  .controller('GraphController', ['$injector', '$scope', '$element',
    function($injector, $scope, $element) {
      // Use the directive's attribute to inject the model.
      var model = $scope.model && $injector.get($scope.model);
      $scope.graph = new GraphControl($element).setModel(model);
    }])
```

Then somewhere else in the app (i.e., not necessarily in the directive/controller's module):

```
angular.module('main', [])

  .factory('SomeGraphModel', function() {
    return new GraphModel();
  })
```